# Can every increasing negative function be expressed as a product with these properties?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples

Let $h:(0,1] \to (-\infty,0)$ be a $C^1$ function, with $h'>0$.

I am looking for **sufficient** conditions on $h$ that imply the existence of $C^1$ functions $\lambda:(0,1] \to (-\infty,0)$, $g:(0,1] \to (0,1]$ such that
$$
h=\lambda g,  \,\,\,\,\,\lambda'>0, \,\,\,\,\,g'<0 \tag{1}
$$

Note that $h'=\lambda' g+\lambda g'>0$,
since both summands are positive. Thus, $h'>0$ is a **necessary condition** for $h$ to be expressible as in $(1)$.

Is it sufficient? Can every $h$ with $h'>0$ be expressed in this way?

---

The motivation for this convoluted question comes from trying to analyses when the solution to a certain minimization  problem is convex. (a bit too long to describe here).

---

**An equivalent reformulation:** (thanks to Alex Jones).

Take any $g: (0,1] \to (0,1]$ with $g' < 0$. Then, we must have $\lambda = h/g < 0$. Since $g > 0$, the condition $\lambda' > 0$ is equivalent to $h'/h < g'/g$.

*So, the question boils down to this:* Does there exist a function $g:(0,1] \to (0,1]$, with $g' < 0$, such that  $h'/h < g'/g$?

Since the quantity $g'/g$ is invariant under positive scaling of $g$ ($g \to c g$ for $c >0$), it suffices to search for bounded $g$.

Note that if $h$ is bounded, then by taking $g=-h$ we get $h'/h = g'/g$ instead of $h'/h < g'/g$. So we are "nearly there".

Comment: Do you mean $g: (0,1] \to (0,1)$?

Comment: I actually meant $g:(0,1] \to (0,1]$. Thanks for your comment, this was a typo. I edited now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always choose $g(x) = 1-e^{h(x)}$. Then $0 < g(x) < 1$ and $g$ is decreasing.

Finally, $\lambda = h/g$ is strictly increasing because
$$
 \lambda(x) = \frac{h(x)}{1-e^{h(x)}} = \phi(h(x))
$$
where
$$
 \phi(u) = \frac{u}{1-e^u}
$$
is strictly increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is clear and elegant as always. You might be interested in this related question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143516/domination-of-derivatives-by-an-involution

Answer (score 0):

Take any $g: (0,1] \to (0,1]$ with $g' < 0$. Then, we can calculate $\lambda = h/g < 0$. Since $g > 0$, the condition $\lambda' > 0$ is equivalent to $h'/h < g'/g$. Integration preserves this inequality, giving $\log h < \log g$, and so $h < g$. This is always true by definition.

**Needs improvement**

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that one can conclude from your analysis that any such $g$ satisfies $ h'/h < g'/g$. This inequality is equivalent to $(\ln(-h))'< (\ln g)'$ and so integration gives (up to additive constants) $-h<g$, which is not a tautology. To conclude, one needs to prove that we can select a suitable $g$ such that $ h'/h < g'/g$.

Comment: @AsafShachar Ah, good catch. Let me see if I can improve it.

Comment: I do think that your direct approach should get us to a solution. What you have done is essentially reformulating the question, removing the "auxiliary variable" $\lambda$.  I have added details about that in the question.

Comment: @AsafShachar Great. I'll leave this answer here for context but Martin seems to have solved it nicely :)

Comment: Are you the same guy who runs infowars